# How to select from two columns in different tables conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
1. products <id, taxon, .... >
2. tags <id, tag_name, product_id, value, ....>
```

I want to join (or do some other operation) on these two tables to get taxon but based on the value of a particular tag_name. Let me make it more clear, if a product has tag with `tag_name=type` and `value=precious`, I want to treat this tag value as a taxon.

So if I have following entries:

```
<# product id:1, taxon:"Jewellery">
<# product id:2, taxon:"Apparel">
<tag id:1, tag_name:"type", product_id:1, value="Precious">
```

I want the following in the result table

```
product_id   taxon_name
    1        Jewellery
    1        Precious
    2        Apparel
```

How can I form such a query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky...

A UNION might do it.  See what this results in:

```
SELECT id,taxon 
 FROM products 
 UNION ALL (
     select product_id as id,value as taxon 
       from tags 
       where tag_name='type' and value='Precious'
  );
```

Basically, that loads `id` and `taxon` from products, and then appends to the end (in a manner of speaking) two relevant columns from the `tags` table.

Comment: Wonderful!! This worked. I have an update though. If tag value is `Silver`, I want to ignore the taxon from the products table. Can this be done?

Comment: The answer has been edited so that only "precious" is included, and "silver" is rejected.